# Create dictionary with default immutable keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash-map, inheritance

I've created a dictionary subclass with a set of default immutable keys.

```
from collections import MutableMapping

class Bones(MutableMapping):
    """Basic dict subclass for bones, that forbids bones from being deleted
    and new bones from being added."""

    def __init__(self, init_val=0):
        self.bones = {"between_hips": init_val,
                      "bicep_right": init_val,
                      "bicep_left": init_val,
                      "arm_right": init_val,
                      "arm_left": init_val,
                      "thigh_right": init_val,
                      "thigh_left": init_val,
                      "leg_right": init_val,
                      "leg_left": init_val,
                      "spine_lower": init_val,
                      "spine_upper": init_val}

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.bones[item]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.bones:
            self.bones[key] = value
        else:
            raise KeyError("Can't add a new bone!")

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        raise TypeError("Can't delete bones")

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.bones)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.bones)
```

Here are a few tests to check that it's working correctly:

```
from bones import Bones

bn = Bones()
bn["between_hips"] = 1

# these should all raise errors
bn["foo"] = 1
del bn["between_hips"]
```

Is this the proper way to create the subclass?

---

## Background

My search to do this correctly started at the StackOverflow question "[How to 'perfectly' override a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3387691/1079075)" where I discovered there were two approaches to doing this. One was sub-classing an Abstract Base Class from the `collections` module and the other was actually sub-classing `dict`.

The justification for actually sub-classing `dict` confused me. Specifically the discussion of the object properties of `__dict__` and `__slots__`. As best as I can tell from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/472000/1079075), I should be using `__slots__`, but I'm super unclear how.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When reading the title of the question, I wondered: "Why use a dict subclass when a regular class with `__slots__` can do?". And judging by the interface, it seems that it may fit.

Slots defines attributes names that are reserved for the use as attributes for the instances of the class. However, no more attributes can be added to the instances when defining `__slots__` on the class:

```
>>> class Example:
...     __slots__ = ('a', 'b', 'c')
... 
>>> e = Example()
>>> e.a = 3
>>> e.d = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'd'
>>> e.a
3
```

However, `__slots__` are not auto-populated and doing so at class level is prohibited:

```
>>> class Example:
...   __slots__ = ('a', 'b', 'c')
...   a = 3
...   b = 4
...   c = 5
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 'a' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable
```

You can, however, still define them in `__init__`:

```
class Bones:
    __slots__ = (
        'between_hips',
        'bicep_right',
        'bicep_left',
        'arm_right',
        'arm_left',
        'thigh_right',
        'thigh_left',
        'leg_right',
        'leg_left',
        'spine_lower',
        'spine_upper',
    )

    def __init__(self, default_value=0):
        for attribute in self.__slots__:
            setattr(self, attribute, default_value)
```

Now the only thing left is to add a dictionary-like interface (and/or inherit from `collections.abc.Mapping`):

```
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        setattr(self, key, value)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__slots__)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__slots__)

    def items(self):
        for attribute in self.__slots__:
            yield attribute, getattr(self, attribute)
```

Or not necessarily, since you can still access the `__slots__` as regular attributes, it all depend on your use case.

Note that with this implementation, you can still delete values, which you try to prohibit in your original implementation:

```
>>> b = Bones()
>>> b.bicep_right
0
>>> b['arm_left'] = 6
>>> b.arm_left
6
>>> del b['leg_left']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __delitem__
>>> del b.leg_left
>>> b.leg_left
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: leg_left
```

If you wish to prevent that, you need to define `__delattr__` on your class as well:

```
    def __delattr__(self, key):
        raise AttributeError(key)
```

Comment: Any reason not to inherit from `typing.Mapping` or `collections.abc.Mapping` to provide the basic scaffolding for a read only `dict` as you've implemented all the abstract methods - and you would get a few extra things for free, e.g. `keys`, `items`, `values`, etc.

Comment: @AChampion no particular reason not to. I don't know the specifics of OP's need. So it's up to them to add it if they want to.

Answer (score 4):

First things first:

- [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) is a storage of unspecified attributes.
  When you create a class and assign a attribute to it, you're by default assigning to this.
- [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#slots) reduces memory, by specifying known attributes of the class. And removing `__dict__` from the class.

The simplest way to show how these work it to mess around with them in the interpreter:

```
>>> class Slots:__slots__=['bar']

>>> s = Slots()
>>> s.__dict__
AttributeError: 'Slots' object has no attribute '__dict__'
>>> s.bar = 'bar'
>>> s.baz = 'baz'
AttributeError: 'Slots' object has no attribute 'baz'
>>> s.__dict__
AttributeError: 'Slots' object has no attribute '__dict__'
>>> class Dict:pass

>>> d = Dict()
>>> d.__dict__
{}
>>> d.bar = 'bar'
>>> d.baz = 'baz'
>>> d.__dict__
{'bar': 'bar', 'baz': 'baz'}
```

And so, if you're writing a class with a specific number of attributes, using `__slots__` can reduce memory consumption, by not using `__dict__`.

To note: this is not specific to your code, this is the same with any and all classes. And in most cases, if you ignore that these exist then your code will still work fine.

---

And so ignoring the above, as it's not needed, we need to look into which is better. Subclassing an ABC, or subclassing `dict`.
To know which is better, you have to understand what [a subclass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)#Subclasses_and_superclasses) and an [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing)#Software_interfaces_in_object-oriented_languages) are.
And what pros and cons come to both.

First, the best example for writing a subclass, is probably `defaultdict`.
This is as a default dict wants to be an exact copy of `dict`, it wants everything it has.
But, it wants to change the usage slightly, so that if a key is missing then you don't get an error.
And so you'd use something like:

```
class DefaultDict(dict):
    __slots__ = ['default_factory']
    def __init__(self, default_factory, d):
        super().__init__(d)
        self._default_factory = default_factory

    def __missing__(self, key):
        ret = self[key] = self._default_factory()
        return ret
```

This, without us having to code it, allows you to use `DefaultDict` almost exactly the same way as `dict`.
It still has `dict.update`, `dict.items`, item getters, setters, and deletors.

To get the same with an ABC, you'd have to add each function to the class like you did.
This is good for cases when you want something that is a mapping, but doesn't have all the attributes or functions that `dict` has.
And so this is the best one to go with, as you *do not want* `dict.update`, as it can add keys that you don't want.

---

To improve your code, I'd recommend that you instead make the core `Bones` class a separate type. Say a 'limited dict', or a 'half frozen dict'.
And then, you can go two routes, 1. subclass, so that you can add more methods, or 2. instantiate.
Showing how you could use 2 would be:

```
from collections import MutableMapping

class LimitedDict(MutableMapping):
    __slots__ = ['_dict']
    def __init__(self, dict):
        self._dict = dict

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._dict[item]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self._dict:
            self._dict[key] = value
        else:
            raise KeyError("Can't add a new bone!")

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        raise TypeError("Can't delete bones")

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._dict)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._dict)

d = LimitedDict({'foo': 'bar'})
```

Comment: Couldn't you simplify by using `Mapping` instead of `MutableMapping`? There's a lot of extras that come with `MutableMapping` that also wouldn't work (`pop`, `update`, `clear`, etc.). These are not defined for `Mapping`. `Mapping` + `__setitem__()` gives what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should rewrite the magic method `__setitem__`(or someone like this) of MutableMapping. Add your immutekey in the magic method.
I rewrite the `__setitem__` of dict to immute some keys like below:

```
class ImmuteKey(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in ['a','b','c']:
            print("%s can't be used as a key!" % key)
        else:
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

>>> a = ImmuteKey()
>>> a['a']='apple'
a can't be used as a key!
>>> a['s'] = 'solo'
>>> a
{'s': 'solo'}
```